# Spark + Flume : "Unable to create Rpc client"

Tags: scala, shell, apache-spark

I am trying to connect a scala spark-shell with a flume agent.

I launch the shell :

```
 ./bin/spark-shell
--jars /Users/romain/Informatique/zoo/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/spark-streaming-flume-sink_2.10-1.6.0.jar 
--jars /Users/romain/Informatique/zoo/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/spark-streaming-flume_2.10-1.6.0.jar 
--jars /Users/romain/Informatique/zoo/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/spark-streaming-flume-assembly_2.10-1.6.0.jar
```

And launch a scala script to listen on port 10000 of localhost :

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.flume._
import org.apache.spark.util.IntParam
 
 
val host          = "localhost"
val port          = 10000
val batchInterval = Milliseconds(5000)
 
// Create the context and set the batch size
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("FlumePollingEventCount")
val ssc            = new StreamingContext(sc, batchInterval)
 
// Create a flume stream that polls the Spark Sink running in a Flume agent
val stream = FlumeUtils.createPollingStream(ssc, host, port)
 
// Print out the count of events received from this server in each batch
stream.count().map(cnt => "Received " + cnt + " flume events." ).print()
 
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Then I configure and start a shell agent :

1) configuration : I make a tail - f on a file appended by another running script (I think it doesn't matter to detail that here)

```
agent1.sources  = source1
agent1.channels = channel1
agent1.sinks    = spark

agent1.sources.source1.type     = exec
agent1.sources.source1.command  = tail -f /Users/romain/Informatique/notebooks/spark_scala/velib/logs/trajets.csv
agent1.sources.source1.channels = channel1

agent1.channels.channel1.type                = memory
agent1.channels.channel1.capacity            = 2000000
agent1.channels.channel1.transactionCapacity = 1000000

agent1.sinks                   = avroSink
agent1.sinks.avroSink.type     = avro
agent1.sinks.avroSink.channel  = channel1
agent1.sinks.avroSink.hostname = localhost
agent1.sinks.avroSink.port     = 10000
```

2) start :

```
./bin/flume-ng agent --conf conf  --conf-file ./conf/avro_velib.conf  --name agent1  -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
```

And then things go ok till an error :

```
2017-02-01 15:09:55,688 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:173)] Starting Sink avroSink
2017-02-01 15:09:55,688 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-1) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.AbstractRpcSink.start(AbstractRpcSink.java:289)] Starting RpcSink avroSink { host: localhost, port: 10000 }...
2017-02-01 15:09:55,688 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:184)] Starting Source source1
2017-02-01 15:09:55,689 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.ExecSource.start(ExecSource.java:169)] Exec source starting with command:tail -f /Users/romain/Informatique/notebooks/spark_scala/velib/logs/trajets.csv
2017-02-01 15:09:55,689 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-1) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.register(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:120)] Monitored counter group for type: SINK, name: avroSink: Successfully registered new MBean.
2017-02-01 15:09:55,689 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-1) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.start(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:96)] Component type: SINK, name: avroSink started
2017-02-01 15:09:55,689 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-1) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.AbstractRpcSink.createConnection(AbstractRpcSink.java:206)] Rpc sink avroSink: Building RpcClient with hostname: localhost, port: 10000
2017-02-01 15:09:55,689 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-1) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.AvroSink.initializeRpcClient(AvroSink.java:126)] Attempting to create Avro Rpc client.
2017-02-01 15:09:55,691 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.register(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:120)] Monitored counter group for type: SOURCE, name: source1: Successfully registered new MBean.
2017-02-01 15:09:55,692 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.start(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:96)] Component type: SOURCE, name: source1 started
2017-02-01 15:09:55,710 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-1) [WARN - org.apache.flume.api.NettyAvroRpcClient.configure(NettyAvroRpcClient.java:634)] Using default maxIOWorkers
2017-02-01 15:10:15,802 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-1) [WARN - org.apache.flume.sink.AbstractRpcSink.start(AbstractRpcSink.java:294)] Unable to create Rpc client using hostname: localhost, port: 10000
org.apache.flume.FlumeException: NettyAvroRpcClient { host: localhost, port: 10000 }: RPC connection error
    at org.apache.flume.api.NettyAvroRpcClient.connect(NettyAvroRpcClient.java:182)
    at org.apache.flume.api.NettyAvroRpcClient.connect(NettyAvroRpcClient.java:121)
    at org.apache.flume.api.NettyAvroRpcClient.configure(NettyAvroRpcClient.java:638)
    at org.apache.flume.api.RpcClientFactory.getInstance(RpcClientFactory.java:89)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.AvroSink.initializeRpcClient(AvroSink.java:127)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.AbstractRpcSink.createConnection(AbstractRpcSink.java:211)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.AbstractRpcSink.start(AbstractRpcSink.java:292)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.start(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:46)
    at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner.start(SinkRunner.java:79)
    at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:251)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error connecting to localhost/127.0.0.1:10000
    at org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyTransceiver.getChannel(NettyTransceiver.java:261)
    at org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyTransceiver.<init>(NettyTransceiver.java:203)
    at org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyTransceiver.<init>(NettyTransceiver.java:152)
    at org.apache.flume.api.NettyAvroRpcClient.connect(NettyAvroRpcClient.java:168)
    ... 16 more
```

Any idea welcom

Answer (score 1):

You should start "listenner"(spark app in your case) first and then launch "writer" (flume-ng)

Comment: ... This is what I descibed here no ?

Comment: Oh,  realy it is,  maybe the problem is in the firewall? Did you stoped it?  And also you can get this error,  if that port is 'occupated' by another process

Comment: I have to say I am on my own laptop on standalone local mode

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ***localhost*** use your ***machine name*** i.e (machine name used in spark conf) in both scala  and avroconf.

```
agent1.sinks.avroSink.hostname = <Machine name>
agent1.sinks.avroSink.port     = 10000
```